# Getting custom sender

Tags: vb.net

I have interesting situation with datagridview.

Under _keydown handler is such code:

```
rowindex = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
Dim cea As New DataGridViewCellEventArgs(4, rowindex)
DataGridView1_CellClick("program", cea)
```

With this I "programatically click" to cell 4 in current row to get my logical program flow.
But I can also click to cell 4 with mouse and same will happen on datagridview.

Question is:
How can I recognize under _CellClick handler of datagridview who activated event (by mouse or by program)? For that purpose I called sender by name "program".

Can I somehow get this name (name of sender) under _CellClick handler and how since I can't cast sender to "program". Or I can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: You shouldn't call event handler methods directly. And fyi that's even not the same as raising the event, since other event handlers aren't executed.

This approach is way better

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender as object, e as DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
   ProcessCellClick(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex, true)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(...)
   rowindex = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
   ProcessCellClick(rowIndex, 4, false)
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessCellClick(rowIndex as Integer, columnIndex as integer, fromCellClickEvent as boolean)
    ...
End Sub
```

That's what I would do.
Anyway, if you just want to check the sender this will help.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender as object, e as DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    if sender.Equals(DataGridView1) then
      ...
    else
      ...
    end if
End Sub

Another approach to check if an event (like TextBox.TextChanged) is initiatet by the user is this one


Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender as object, e as DataGridViewCellEventArgs)

    If me.ActiveControl Is DataGridView1 Then
       ' DataGridView is focused
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hm, in that place It is convenient for me to call handler as a function. And, If I think so maybe will then be most simple and useful to simply involve one public variable which will tell in _CellClick if "program clicked" to datagridview.